# Asp.net crystal report (dynamic change)

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi all !
                I am developing one asp.net application and the requirement is as below.
user can view multiple reports(i have used crystal reports). Each report has edit report button.when the user click on edit button,then report will be open in **excel** sheet on different webpage.then user make suitable changes like sorting etc and save this report and take an updated print.

Comment: So far you have only stated your requirement. You haven't explained [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) in order to implement this requirement and what particular difficulties you encountered when you attempted to do so. I am afraid that there's isn't enough information in your question so that it can be answered.

Comment: at present the user can view crystal reports but i dont know how to convert this crystal report to excel sheet at server side..and how will user dynamically make changes in excel sheet and save it.

Answer (score 0):

- Drag & drop many `CristalReportsViewer` in the page, one for each report you want to show
- Drag & drop many `CristalReportsSource` in the page,  one for each report you want to show
- link each `CristalReportsSource` to a `CristalReportsViewer`
- set for each `CristalReportsSource` the relative source `myreport.rpt`
- put many buttons that export the reports, using this sample code

  ```
  protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
  {
  // Stop buffering the response
  Response.Buffer = false;
  // Clear the response content and headers
  Response.ClearContent();
  Response.ClearHeaders();

  ExportFormatType format = ExportFormatType.Excel;
  try
  {
     reportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(format, Response, true, "report.xls");

  }
  catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
  {
      //happens; no matter
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     Response.Write(ex.StackTrace);
  }
  }
  ```

---

You can show a single report, and allow users choosing the desired report unsing a dropdown with this sample code

```
    reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
    string reportName = "myreport.rpt";
    reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/{0}/{1}", "MyReportsFolder", reportName)));
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
    reportDocument.ReadRecords();
```